# How to parse ms-office docs

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, file-format

I need to create a application (preferably in c#/win32) to open a office doc [97-2003 format] ( Word, PPT, EXCEL) and parse the data structures, validate the fields, values and cross references, show the errors found in the document and possible solutions to fix the errors in document as per specification.

Are there any tools available / open source library or documentations.

Can "Office Interop" help for parsing the details.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105.aspx

Comment: Presently it's "I need" only, first for ppt format. Later it will be "We need" for all formats :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

People recommend [NPOI](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/) for such tasks

It's an open source library for .NET which do not require Office to be installed.